# How many 5-digit numbers are there with number 2 and 3 following each other. No repetition of digits allowed.

Tags: combinatorics

According to the answer sheet:

Case 1:
If number 2 comes first in the 5-digit number, we can choose remaining numbers in 8*7*6 different ways.

Case 2: 
The number of ways to place number 2 and 3 after each other so that number 2 doesn't appear first can be formed in 3*7*7*6 ways, because the numbers 2 and 3 can be placed on 3 different places. And we can choose the first number in 7 different ways (can't be 0), and the remaining numbers in 7*6 different ways.

So, I understand the first case. What I don't get is the second case.
Let's say I put the sequence of numbers like this: "_ _ _ 2 3" and decide to pick the third number first (8 ways), then the second number (7 ways) and lastly the first number (5 ways). I won't get the same result, so my question is: why do I have to do this in order, starting from the first digit?

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessarily $5$ ways for the first number. If you'd picked $0$ earlier, then it'd be $6$. On the other hand, starting from the first number avoids this problem.

---

If you wish to count starting from the third digit or similar, then you need to split it into cases. You'd then get the same result as before.

$$\underbrace{7*6*5}_{\text{No $0$s}}+\underbrace{1*7*6}_{\text{$0$ for third digit}}+\underbrace{7*1*6}_{\text{$0$ for second digit}}=7*7*6$$

Answer (score 0):

Lock the 2, and the 3 together like they are a single digit.

So we have the permutations of the set {0,1,23,4,5,6,7,8,9}

With the further constraints that.
we must include the member 23 somewhere in the choosing.
and we will be selecting 4 numbers.

We can't lead with 0.  But I am not going to address this in the initial calculation.

$8\cdot 7\cdot 6$ allocates the digits that surround "$23$"
and there are 4 slots to drop the "$23$"

and we must subtract those counted that start with $0$

$8\cdot 7\cdot 6\cdot 4 - 1\cdot 7\cdot 6\cdot 3$

Answer (score 0):

The pestiferous $0$ is a problem only if it appears *and* becomes a leading zero, $Pr = \frac38\cdot\frac14 = \frac3{32}$

thus ans = $8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot4\cdot\frac{29}{32}$